# How can I obtain the address of a closure in Rust?

Tags: rust

```rs
let say_hello = || println!("hello");
```

How can I display the address of the closure?

Comment: What are you doing with the address? Beware that Rust has a propensity to move objects around, closures included, so the address isn't stable like it would be for a static function.

Comment: @JohnKugelman need it as key to a map

Comment: And what will you do once Rust has moved the closure and its new address no longer matches the key you used to store data in the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a raw pointer conversion:

```rust
fn main() {
    let say_hello = || println!("hello");
    let address = (&say_hello as *const _) as usize;
    println!("{address}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d2e08f5a5704147176da79dc45ded94)

Also using [`std::ptr::addr_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/macro.addr_of.html) and casting again:

```rust
let same_address = std::ptr::addr_of!(say_hello) as usize;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67b6203c90f9417ab4bf7d7c5268fc41)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question *really* depends on whether you mean the closure object itself, or the closure's call function.

For example, in this case, the closure captures a variable:

```rs
let mut foo = 0;

let mut bar = || foo += 1;
```

And hence, `bar` must carry within it a `&mut foo`.

Therefore, the address of the actual code which is run is different from the address of the closure object.

To concrete this distinction, examine this example:

```rs
fn foo() {}

let bar = foo; // `bar` itself is the address of the code for foo.
println!("{:?}", bar as usize); // Prints the address of the code of foo.
println!("{:?}", &bar as *const _ as usize); // Prints the address of `bar`
```

The second line is essentially what @Netwave's answer does above.

If you are instead looking for the first case, then this isnt necessarily always possible.

If your closure captures items, then it can't be converted to an address of the code in stable rust, since this'd require you have access to it's implementation of `FnOnce`/`Fn`/`FnMut`. However, if you're ok with unstable rust, here's how you'd do it:

```rs
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]

fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    let mut foo = || x += 1;
    
    print_addr(foo);
}

fn print_addr<F: FnMut()>(_: F) {
    println!("{:?}", <F as std::ops::FnMut<()>>::call_mut as usize);
}
```

If your closure *doesn't* capture anything, then the correct way to get the address is to cast it to a function pointer and then cast that to a number:

```rs
fn main() {
    let foo = || println!("Abc");
    
    println!("{:?}", foo as fn() as usize);
}
```